# SnowSQL connection issue with Snowflake

Tags: csv, authentication, connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting the error below. I believe there is a configuration issue between snowsql and my trial snowflake account.

```
C:\Users\barberc> snowsql -a tyXXXXX.us-east-2 -u XXXXXX@gmail.com
Password:
250001 (n/a): Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!
```

I have also tried appending the ".aws" on it, but that doesn't seem to help.

I am trying to load data from a .csv into a database to work with.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LCcg.png).

Comment: Are you able to connect via web UI?

Comment: Do you have a proxy in between? Especially an SSL proxy? Run [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) to see if connectivity is the issue.

Comment: For any issues related to SnowSQL, use -o log_level=DEBUG -o log_file=<path for log file> which would give a lot more details and information related to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should run this SQL command to get your Snowflake account URL

```
use role accountadmin;
select system$whitelist();
```

Look for

```
[{"type":"SNOWFLAKE_DEPLOYMENT","host":"xxxxx.ap-southeast-2.snowflakecomputing.com","port":443},
```

Extract the hostname before snowflakecomputing.com, that would be the account name to use in snowsql.

In this example, it will be

```
snowsql -a xxxxx.ap-southeast-2
```

You may also want to check with curl command, to make sure you can reach the Snowflake account.

```
curl -vvv https://xxxxx.ap-southeast-2.snowflakecomputing.com/console/login
```

If you found HTTP 200, that means a connection is established. Otherwise, there could be a proxy/firewall or routing issue.